# Computing power (1-beta) for GLMM in SPSS

Tags: spss, statistical-power, glmm

How do I compute power (1-beta) for GLMM in SPSS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, power depends on the link function, the distribution family, the model forms of both the fixed and the random effects, the distribution of predictors, the relationship between the predictors and the outcome, and the null hypothesis.

There is almost certainly no closed form solution to your problem. and probably also no built-in function.

[I recommend simulation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/471539/1352)

Comment: Thank you. Can I do it in R?

Comment: Yes, in R it is probably much easier than in SPSS (which I don't have a lot of experience with). Take a look at the linked answer, you could do something similar.